# Why is React Native state not properly being set when I tap a button in navigationOptions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-state

I have a React Native screen/component in which there is a menu button in the top-left corner of the nav/header. When that button is tapped, I want to make a menu within the screen/component itself toggle open and shut.

For whatever reason though, with how I have it set up now, the first time I tap the menu button, the menu opens, but after that, it always stays open and doesn't close, no matter how many times I tap the button. It seems like the state is not properly being updated or something.

Here's the basic code I have for the menu toggling:

```
const Screen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setParams({
            toggleMenu: () => {
                setShowMenu(!showMenu);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            { showMenu &&
                <FlatList
                    // Menu code here.
                />
            }
            {/* Other screen rendering here. */}
        </View>
    );
};

Screen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;

    return {
        headerLeft: () => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={params.toggleMenu}
                >
                    <Text>Menu</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            );
        }
    };
};

export default Screen;
```

I'm thinking that it might be some closure issue, but I'm really not sure. I added a `console.log` to `toggleMenu`, and the `showMenu` value is always `false` when I enter into the function, which then sets it to `true`, thus while the menu won't close.

Why the `showMenu` value is always `false`, even after I use `setShowMenu` to set it to `true` is beyond me though. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stale closure in your `useEffect`. Its one of the most common problems people run into with hooks. Change it to use the updater form and it should start working.

```js
setShowMenu(prevVal => !prevVal);
```

`showMenu` is basically stuck at it's initial value inside the `useEffect`, so every time the update is called it is doing `setShowMenu(!false)`. That's why it appears to work the first time.

The updater form guarantees that you will be working with the most recent copy of state.

Comment: That was it, 100%. Thank you so much! I've never heard of that updater form. Is this a common thing you have to do in React Native? Is it JSX? There any documentation to read more about this so I can better understand it? Thank you so much.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: It's recommended to use a functional update when your new state value is derived from the previous state

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Brian.